# Is it possible to dockerize Django flatpages?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I need to handle Django pages that don't have their own app, and the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/flatpages/) recommends I use flatpages for one-off pages. However, these pages are stored in the database attached to Django, not the filesystem.

This is causing issues because I can't transfer data in the database the same way I can transfer files in the filesystem.

When I run the website through docker-compose, it starts with a fresh postgres image with no data. As a result, the flatpages are left behind anytime I re-run the docker container without migrating all of the data.

The only solution I can think of is simply copying over the flatpages manually every time I bring the website to a new machine. Unfortunately, this seems like a terrible solution because it adds more deployment steps and goes against the ideology of dockerizing websites.

Is there a better solution available?

Comment: persist your data volume in docker container https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: @iklinac Hmm. I need to do much more reading about volumes, but it seems like if I used them I would then need to transfer the volume between machines manually.

Comment: There is no certain benefit of docker when you consider data migration, PostgreSQL backup, volume or whatever you decide to be a data migration step will always be required no matter of environment

Comment: Can you not store the flatpages in a fixture and load the fixture into a local sqlite db? Not ideal but its an option.

Comment: @iklinac I understand, however, I was hoping to be able to run a development version of the website without needing to migrate live data. As it stands, I will need to do a data migration to get the flatpages, do testing, then do another data migration if I want to transfer live data. I was hoping to avoid doing two different data migrations.

Comment: @MattSeymour This might actually be what I need. I'll have to look into it.

Comment: considering your flatpages are editable database rows they are really not a static data so something you can do is use fixtures or database migrations but be careful if users also can edit flatpages  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/initial-data/
I would still advise backup of django_flatpage and django_flatpage_sites  tables

Comment: @iklinac That link is perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (semi-tested) solution I've found is to use a Django [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations), and run the command `python manage.py migrate --noinput` before starting the server via my docker-compose file.

The data migration itself makes use of the "RunPython" operation, which allows the creation of a hard-coded flatpages through python.

The rough draft of my migration looks like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

FLATPAGES = [
    {
        "title": "Home",
        "url": "/home/",
        "content": "",
        "enable_comments": False,
        "template_name":"home.html",
        "registration_required": False
    },
]


def add_flatpages_data(apps, schema_editor):

    site = Site.objects.create(domain='domain.here', name='name.here')

    for page_dict in FLATPAGES:
        new_page = FlatPage.objects.create(
            title=page_dict['title'],
            url=page_dict['url'],
            content=page_dict['content'],
            enable_comments=page_dict['enable_comments'],
            template_name=page_dict['template_name'],
            registration_required=page_dict['registration_required'],
            )
        new_page.sites.add(site)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(
            add_flatpages_data,
        ),
    ]
```

This isn't pretty, and I don't think it's good whatsoever, but it's the only solution I have found thus far.
As it turns out, Django's fixtures will not work for this application, as Fixtures can only be used for models defined in an app created by the developer. The only reason this is the case is that Django tries to read the fixture's model as "app.model", and thus will not accept the model "django.contrib.flatpages.FlatPage", despite it being just as valid.

I would still like improvements and alternate solutions from others, but I thought I should document my findings.